# Cannot be cast automatically to type integer

Tags: python, django, postgresql

> django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column "name_id" cannot be cast automatically to type integer

This error continues to appear when I try to make migrations, I tried dropping the database, commenting all models, nothing works.

Comment: Please post your model code.

Comment: You should look into migrations code, to find out, which migration and where tries to cast some fields, which are not integer, to int.

Answer (score -1):

Removing all previous migrations solved the problem